# Even though gd library is enabled in windows imagecreatefromjpeg() is throwing error

Tags: php, laravel, gd, undefined-function, imagecreatefrompng

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYU00.jpg)[enter image description here][2]    Error:-  Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()

Function trigger:`$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);` // $source - some path of the image

> called from: helper(laravel-framework of php)
>
> Description:Function call works fine when called from controller but
>   it is not woirking when called from Job
>
> First attempt:Gd library is enabled in php.ini file
>
> Any one faced this issue?

Comment: i think you have two different `php.ini` one for web and second for console

Comment: No i do have only one php.ini file

Comment: How do you determin that GD is enabled? Does `phpinfo` list it?

Comment: yes.i wil share screen shot

Comment: And what do you mean by "but it is not woirking when called from Job" - what is this "job"? Something on the shell? Then a screenshot of your webserver's `phpinfo` is irrelevant. Does `php -m` list gd?

Comment: Just run this command on the command line:
`php -m`
or this for more information:
`php -i`

Comment: when we dont want the server to load we put the code which takes time like(image compression,sending mail)into job in laravel

Answer (score 0):

Issue reolved.I had not removed semi-colon in php.ini in wamp